Go type assertion to detect other types of maps
I have a function which takes a variable list of arguments of type any.
This function handles many different types, but there are a few that it cannot handle.
It can handle maps of type map[string]string, but it cannot accept maps of any other type, key or value. How can I easily detect these conditions without having to explicitly list every single other type of map ([string]int, [int]string, [string]any, etc):
func f(arguments ...any) error {
   for _, a := range arguments {
       switch a.(type) {
       case string:
           // do stuff with a string
       case int:
           // do stuff with an int
       case map[string]string:
           // do stuff with this type of map
       case map[string]int:
           return fmt.Errorf("This is not an acceptable map type")
           // and so forth for other types of maps
       default:
           // I want the default to handle native handling for what happens next
       }
   }
   return nil
}

I want to keep the default case and I was hoping I could subnest another assertion for the map key/value types, but I'm not seeing anything.

The default clause is the typical place to handle an unknown type.  What does the program do in the default clause?  What is the "native handling"?

"How can I easily detect these conditions" you cannot. "without having to explicitly list every single other type of map" you cannot do this either. What you can do is fall back to reflection.

Use reflection (Go Playground):
func f(arguments ...any) error {
    for _, a := range arguments {
        t := reflect.TypeOf(a)
        switch t.Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            // do stuff with a string

        case reflect.Int:
            // do stuff with an int

        case reflect.Map:
            switch k, v := t.Key().Kind(), t.Elem().Kind(); {
            case k == reflect.String && v == reflect.String:
                // do stuff with this type of map
            case k == reflect.String && v == reflect.Int:
                return fmt.Errorf("This is not an acceptable map type")

                // and so forth for other types of maps
            }

        default:
            // I want the default to handle native handling for what happens next
        }
    }

    return nil
}

